# Android: Android 4.4.4 WebView upload image, but JavaScript check file type error

Tags: javascript, image, webview, image-uploading, android-4.4-kitkat

I use Android WebView to show a web server's web page in Android 4.4.4.
But at the server side, JavaScript check for the image file type fails. So I cannot upload my image.

But without changing the server side code, I can upload image successfully in iOS WebView and on desktop using the same image file.

The following is my Server side JavaScript image checker code

```
var check_file = function (file) {
    if (file.size > 1048576 * 10) {
      upload_err_hdlr(413);
      return false;
    }
    alert("Before Check");
    if (!file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|png|gif|jpg)/)) {
      alert("Check fail");
      upload_err_hdlr(415);
      return false;
    }
    alert("Check successfully");
    return true;
};
```

after I upload the image via Android 4.4.4 WebView, it shows an alert dialog
1. Before Check
2. Check fail

The following is my Android code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.30:5000/dashboard");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
            if(mUploadMessage == null)
                return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            Log.d("Ting", "after result:" + result);
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    }

}
```

The Android log "Ting" shows:

02-02 11:44:14.782 12456 12456 D Ting    : after result:content://media/external/images/media/12255

The Uri is **content://media/external/images/media/12255**

This is the uploaded fail image
[image]

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

======================
Additional Information:
I print the file content in JavaScript.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(file));
```

And the shows

```
{"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModified Date":"2015-01-17T10:04:30.000Z","name":"12255","type":"","size":2369496}
```

It seems that the uploaded image file has no "type" attribute.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273236/android-webview-upload-image-at-android-client-side-cannot-get-the-file-type-i

Answer (score 0):

it's because file type isn't supported in Mobile browsers , 
check [File type Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type)

You can try to check the file type using Regular expression :

```js
if((/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test("filename")) {
  // the file is an image 
} else {
   //file type is different than (JPEG,PNG,GIF,TIFF)
}
```