# Android WebView: Upload image at Android client side. Cannot get the file type in Server side JavaScript

Tags: android, webview, image-uploading

I've tested all the available code on stackOverFlow, but it's still not working.

I use Android 4.4.4 and use WebView to upload image to Server web page, but it fails to get the file type in Server JavaScript code

```
alert("type:" + input.files[0].type);
```

If I add the file type check code, this will fail.

**I've tested it on desktop (Ubuntu) Chrome, Firefox and on iOS UIWebView. All of them work. The server side will print the file type.
Only Android 4.4.4 WebView fails.**

Server **upload_file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' class="imageUpload" multiple="true" />
        <div class="imageOutput"></div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $images = $('.imageOutput')

            $(".imageUpload").change(function(event){
                readURL(this);
            });

            function readURL(input) {

                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    alert("type:" + input.files[0].type);        

                    $.each(input.files, function() {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {           
                            alert("path:" + e.target.result);
                            $images.append('<img src="'+ e.target.result+'" />')
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(this);
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Client (Android) **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;

    WebView mWebView;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){


                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);

            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.30/upload_file.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if(requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
            if(mUploadMessage == null)
                return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            Log.d("Ting", "after result:" + result);
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    }
```

Anyone has ideas how to get the correct file type?

Thanks.
Eric

Comment: Did you add permissions in your Manifest?

Comment: I've editted the original post, my question is "I cannot get the file type in JavaScript"

Comment: Please make your question more clear , where you are getting problem in FileType! in web-side code or in Android code

Comment: In web-side code, I cannot get the FileType if I use Android WebView.
But I can get the FileType at server side if I use Android Browser or Chrome  Browser or iOS UIWebView

Comment: openFileChooser not called when is clicked on android 4.4 webview, see : https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Kitkat-WebView

Comment: @HenryChuang OK, I'll check the post, but after I added the openFileChooser() function, it will be called. I've printed the log inside the function.

Comment: @HenryChuang Hi Henry, the github sample code seems to be unrelated to this question.
My question is I cannot get the "file type" in server side JavaScript code.

Comment: Have you found a way to solve this? I'm working with Cropit JS on a WebView app, and this has always been a headache. Images don't load on Android KitKat

Answer (score 1):

The support for file uploads in Android's `WebView` started in Android 2.2. It worked fine until 4.3 (included). 4.4 did not have file upload support which was only re-introduced in 5.0.

However, if you take a closer look at Android 4.4, you'll see that this has been (partly) fixed in versions 4.4.3 and 4.4.4.

These two versions offer file upload support again. However, the drawback is that there's a bug on those two versions where file extensions will be removed so that the MIME type is always `application/octet-stream`.

You may take a look at this library:

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Here's the method to check for file upload availability:

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/ecff154ef390a0dbdb5337bd5dea2055205c104f/Source/src/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L1011

Answer (score 0):

you can get the realPath from Uri.then use the methed Uri.from(File file) get the new Uri.At last, use new uri can get the file extension